# openstack ansible deployment fail after creating lxc containers while running apt-get update command inside container

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, lxc, openstack

The openstack ansible created containers where running but they don't have access to internet. When I manually add routing then I get following error:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
```

```
# lxc-ls -f
NAME                                STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS            IPV4                         IPV6 UNPRIVILEGED
infra1_galera_container-40eb8c2c    RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.232               -    false
infra1_glance_container-fe32f950    RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.194, 10.200.75.51 -    false
infra1_heat_api_container-fcdda89c  RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.207               -    false
infra1_horizon_container-29382c02   RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.140               -    false
infra1_keystone_container-c4b4bca5  RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.61                -    false
infra1_memcached_container-667ec859 RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.183               -    false
infra1_nova_api_container-6dcd2a9b  RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.114               -    false
infra1_placement_container-d9a47077 RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.218               -    false
infra1_rabbit_mq_container-34797cf1 RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.210               -    false
infra1_repo_container-02a62c03      RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.94                -    false
infra1_utility_container-a23621d0   RUNNING 1         onboot, openstack 192.168.56.90                -    false
```

also thing is my lxc bridge has some different network & that is not getting assigned

```
lxcbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
```

my openstack_user_config.yml defines all infra components on 192.168.56.0/24 network.

Why by default when I run the playbook I don't get internet access on containers? did I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

Internet access to lxc containers is provided through lxcbr0. Each container should get an IP 10.0.3.0/24 subnet assigned to eth0 (default interface). I have the same issue, which is caused by dnsmasq not handling DHCP request sent to lxcbr0. Restarting dnsmasq works. Following are the steps I took:

Check if DHCP requests are handled with tcpdump on controller host:

```
tcpdump -ntv -i lxcbr0
```

Restart dnsmasq:

```
ps aux | grep dnsmasq
# note pid and copy dnsmasq command
kill dnsmasq-pid
rerun dnsmasq command
```

or with 
    systemctl start lxc-dnsmasq.service

Answer (score 0):

There should be a need to check the `/etc/resolv.conf`

The correct nameserver is not added there because this under container apt update is failed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).